# Error while exporting multiple files

Tags: export, scripting, procedural-programming

I have two questions. I am trying to export results from my calculation when I iterate. I am processing multiple files using code below:

```
processFile[fileName_] :=
 Module[{data},
  data = Import[fileName, "Data"];
  (*Here I have all my function and processing that I don't want to include here*)
  Results1 = Table[{(ii 5) - 2.5, Abs[Mean[bin[5, ii]]]}, {ii, 1, 200}];
  (*then here I want to export the resulting table*)
  Export["Results_" <> fileName <> ".csv" , Results1]
```

When I want to loop with multiple files I use this command :

```
files = FileNames[NotebookDirectory[] <> "*.txt"];
Do[Print["Processing file ", files[[n]]];
processFile[files[[n]]], {n, 1, 2}]
```

I got an error, because in `Export` command `fileName` should come before "Results_",
so I changed it to

`Export[fileName <> "Results_" <>  ".csv" , Results1]`

It gives no error, but I wonder if there is a way to fix this issue without moving `fileName`?

Also 
As you see the files that I import are .txt, but I want to export in .csv,

When I export, the exported files contain .txt attached, for example 
("file1.txtResults.csv") 
How to get rid of .txt in the name?

Thank you,

Comment: <> is a concatenation operator, so "file1.txtResults.csv" is exactly what you asked for in "Results_" <> fileName <> ".csv".  You likely want to remove the "txt" in your loop.

Comment: if i remove .txt it will read all the files, and that is not what i want

Comment: I think you want `Export["Results_" <> FileBaseName@fileName <> ".csv" , Results1]`

Comment: You are mixing contexts.  In your module, you need to strip the "txt". Rohit has suggested one way.

Comment: Thanks @RohitNamjoshi it worked